# Access un synchronized map from multiple classes

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

This question came up out of curiosity , i have three classes `A`, `B` and `C` .

- class `A` has a member variable Map say `sharedMap`
- class B and class C is accessing Class A's `sharedMap` and trying to change the values of the map as per their needs.

The problem is- I cant change anything in class `A` as i don't have control on class `A` (can not use synchronize keyword or method to synchronize the Map) is there any way to still manage the synchronization of class `A`'s `sharedMap`?

Comment: Make a class D with a synchronized accessor? Probably not an elegant solution, but, seems like there is some strange design decisions being made.

Comment: I suggest you to write snippets of code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: You can use a `Semaphore` in a "pool" class to determine whose turn (`B`or `C`) is to access `sharedMap`.

Comment: You say "synchronized" in your question, but you don't say anything about _threads_.  The fact that code in three different classes access the same object is irrelevant.  The question is, how many different _threads_ run that code?

Answer (score 1):

Use composition - instead of creating an instance of A just wrap it inside some other class and expose the map using a synchronized method. If A is implementing some interfaces then that wrapping class should also implement them and just delegate all the calls to A. So basically something like

```
class WrappedA implements InterfaceA {
  private A inner = new A(); // don't expose A's instances to other classes
  public synchronized void mapManipulator() {
   // do something with inner.map
  }
  @Override
  public void interfaceMethodA() {
   // IF any of those methods are using the map, remember to synchronize
   inner.interfaceMethodA();
  }
}
```

Since it's your code you can make such a change. If you can't make even that (something else is creating A?) then A will always be exposed to other classes so you have to just make a convention that all other classes will call it through some new class but this will be very error prone if someone forgets to use the wrapper instead of A.

Any more details regarding the context might help to come up with something better...